# iOS - if user allow using his current location or not

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mapkit, cllocationmanager

in my app in map view i want to show the nearest 10 stores for the user's current location

but first i have to take current location first then i can show the stores according to user's location

in first start of the app the app ask user if he allow to get current location or not so i must do something like

if user allow
list stores on map
else 
go back to main page

now i am using the code below:

```
 mtMap.showsUserLocation=YES;
mymanager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
mymanager.delegate=self;
CLLocation *location = [mymanager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2 = [location coordinate];

NSString *latitude1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate2.latitude]; 
NSString *longitude1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate2.longitude];

NSString *myURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/aaaaa.ashx?term=%@,%@",latitude1,longitude1];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
NSInputStream *dataStream=[[NSInputStream alloc]initWithData:data];

[dataStream open];
if(dataStream)
{

    NSError *err=nil;
    id jsonobject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:dataStream options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
    if([jsonobject respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)])
    {
        //fill arr
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work for the first time when the user opens the app because of late allowing or getting current location late i can't reach where he is so i can't show nearest places

there can be a problem with my logic. i mean may be i shouldn't do all the job in viewDidload

so could anyone help how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it under the viewDidLoad section, what about inserting the code in this method?

```
// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol. 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 
CLLocation *location = newLocation;
...
```

That would make the code run once the user's location was updated. 
You could also add an if statement inside the method to check if it is the first time the code has been run and if not to return.

Comment: yes it is a good idea but isnt this time it always run? i just want to run once so can i stop updating location or another idea? thanks